# How to fix drop table migration rollback with empty down method

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I made a mistake at work by running `rake db:migrate`with bunch of migrations.  I ran `rake db:rollback` to roll those back to previous state.  One of the migrations had drop table in the "up" method.  The same migration's "down" method was empty.  Now rails keeps complaining that this table does not exist in mysql, and it will not start.  I see in schema.rb this table is not present anymore.  Just to be thorough we have two app servers, and 2 rails admin servers running this code.  This issue is happening on rails_admin servers only.
Is there a way to fix this error.

**EDIT:** These tables are not needed anymore, so don't care about the data.  I just want to be able to start my app without seeing the error "mysql2::error: table "xyz" doesn't exit

Comment: Restore your admin server's database from backups. If you don't have backups then all the data is gone and the best you can do is look through `schema.rb`'s revision history (which surely you must have in your revision control system) and recreate the table, if you don't have backups then all that table's data is basically gone.

Comment: @muistooshort i dont care about the data.  those tables are not needed anymore.  what im seeing is an error "mysql2::error: table "xyz" doesn't exit.  It won't let me load the app

Comment: Then recreate the table based on `schema.rb`'s revision history. Then figure out what is trying to use this table that is no longer needed and fix that.

Comment: is it a good idea to create tables manually, instead of migrations? @muistooshort  just wondering if it would cause any issues later

Comment: Generally no, but as a quick hack to get a production server up and running again, sure, you do what you have to do and then go back and clean up after. Create it manually and regenerate `schema.rb` or write a migration to create it, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new migration this way (You can find the table structure in your previous migrations.)

```
def change
  unless(table_exists? :your_table_name)
    create_table :your_table_name do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```